# cant figure out the syntax to use the variables i have to search if a user has a role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My code so far correctly gathers the server id I want to search in, the role id I want to find, and the guild owner id of whomever invited the bot.

what I need it to do is check if that `OwnerId` has the role I mentioned earlier in the server.

here is what I got so far, but I feel like I'm missing something simple.

```js
/// adding a guild to the database upon invite
bot.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
    // Guild the user needs to have the role in
    let guildA = process.env.BOT_GUILD;
    console.log(guildA);

    // Role that the user needs
    let requiredRole = process.env.PAID_ROLE;
    console.log(requiredRole);

    // Member object of the user in guildA
    let guildOwner = await guild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);
    
    let OwnerId = guildOwner.guild.ownerID;
    console.log(OwnerId);
    
    //Check if they have the role 
    if (guildA.OwnerId.cache.has(`${requiredRole}`))
```

I also tried to add `.roles` after `OwnerId` and before `.cache`, but I get an error.

If someone has more info on how this sort of thing works as well that would be great, idk exactly what to google for this.

Comment: maybe try console.logging  the `guildOwner` object and see if any fields may help. It seems like you are trying to guess the fields. Log it out and check.

Comment: oh no thats what i mean. the first 3 catch it fine. the next line after guildOwner fetches the owners discord id. so like i said i have all 3 ids i need. i just dont know how to use them to search

Comment: I mean log the `guildOwner` variable. `console.log(guildOwner)` and see what comes out. Its probably a object with a `roles` property. `guildA.OwnerId.cache` doesn't look like it will ever work since `guildA` looks to be an env var (which is a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OwnerId` won't have any roles as it's just a snowflake/ID. If you want to check if the guild owner has the role with the ID of `process.env.PAID_ROLE` (if it's an ID and not just a role name...), you can fetch the owner as a member, and check if their [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache)' cache [`has`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) this ID:

```js
bot.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
  // guild the user needs to have the role in
  // do you use it anywhere?!
  let guildA = process.env.BOT_GUILD;

  // member object of the owner of the guild the bot just joined
  let guildOwner = await guild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);

  // check if that guildOwner has the role required
  let ownerHasPaidRole = guildOwner.roles.cache.has(process.env.PAID_ROLE);

  if (ownerHasPaidRole)
    console.log(`Woohoo, ${guildOwner} has the required role`);
});
```

Edit: If you want to fetch the member belonging to your guild with the ID of `process.env.BOT_GUILD`, you will need to use `YOUR_GUILD#members.fetch(guild.ownerID)`. To get your guild by its ID, you can fetch it too. [`bot.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) returns all of the guilds the bot is currently handling, so you can use its [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch) method

```js
bot.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
  // guild the user needs to have the role in
  let myGuild = await bot.guilds.fetch(process.env.BOT_GUILD);

  // get the member object of the owner on myGuild
  let guildOwner = await myGuild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID)

  if (!guildOwner)
    return console.log(`Oops, ${guild.owner} is not a member of your server.`)

  // check if that guildOwner has the role required on myGuild
  let ownerHasPaidRole = guildOwner.roles.cache.has(process.env.PAID_ROLE);

  if (ownerHasPaidRole)
    console.log(`Woohoo, ${guildOwner} has the required role`);
});
```

Comment: the problem is the object that comes back has information on the server that JOINED not MY server. so my idea was to pull the owner id of the server that just invited the bot and then find that id in my server hence why i pull the owner id. 

also yes. BOT_GUILD and PAID_ROLE are both ids not names

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. I've just updated my answer. I hope that's what you meant :)